How to implement E2E encryption in a multi-user app?
I'm running an SaaS application with support for multiple tenants. Each tenant can have multiple users assigned. Those users collaborate on a database of documents that's owned by the tenant. With my current implementation, I use server-side encryption: Each tenant has a secret key that is used to symmetrically encrypt data before saving it to the database and to decrypt it when it's received. The sole purpose of this is so that my monolith application does not have access to any sensible data (in case it's getting compromised). I run a very small separate app (think Hashicorp Vault), that provides the tenant secret key for a correctly signed token from my IdP.
Now I want to extend this existing functionality and allow each tenant to enable full end-to-end encryption. The way I imagine this to work is that I would throw away the tenant secret and instead, for each user, generate their own secret that is not stored on the server, but in the local storage of the client app and use this to encrypt the tenant secret. Afterwards, I would move all encryption/decryption operations from the server to the client. When data is loaded in the client, I would send the users encrypted tenant key along in the response, he encrypts the tenant key with his own user secret from local storage and then in turn can use the decrypted tenant key to decrypt the payload.
Given that this sentence already sounds strange, it's probably the wrong approach. But just for you to understand where I'm coming from.
Being a software dev and not a cryptography expert, I'm wondering if this is the correct way to do it. Basically what I want is to enable multiple people working on end-to-end encrypted common data. When one person is added or removed, I don't want to re-encrypt all data, so this is why probably encrypting the original key instead of the data itself is the way to go - but then, isn't encrypting the same secret multiple times a problem when it comes to pattern recognition? Additionally, I'd like to completely hide the central secret (so the tenant secret) from the users. Normally that being visible to users of the tenant wouldn't be a problem in and of itself, unless they happen to fish it from the browser's dev tools and store it, which would allow them to decrypt that data, even if access for the user was revoked (if they anyhow manage to get hold of the encrypted data). And overall, is this the way to go, or how would you approach something like that?
For some background, I'm using AES-256 symmetic crypto using the native NodeJS crypto module.
Currently I didn't try to implement any proof of concept as conceptionally it's not really clear to me how I can approach a use-case like that.
Optimally, I'd like to use an existing solution, but looking into the Signal protocol and PGP, they seem to serve different purposes. I think my requirement of having data already encrypted and sharing access between a changing set of users is the key differentiation. If there's any solution to that existing as a protocol/library already, that would be awesome.

Be careful, implementing your own crypto is dangerous (that's why some libraries are called "Hazmat" for "Hazardous Material", and error might quickly make your implementation, at most, useless. Have you checked solutions that offer that kind of technology ? You might try something like seald.io for example.
